# How to import org.apache.commons.collections4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to use

> CollectionUtils.isEmpty

function in my spring mvc project. To do that I added following block to my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

and my java class is:

```
import org.apache.commons.collections4;
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> empty_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(empty_list)) {
            System.out.println("List is empty");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I got the following error:

> java: package org.apache.commons.collections4 does not exist

It is already in my pom.xml file, what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you rebuild/reload your project after the pom was changed?

Comment: Why don't you just use `empty_list.isEmpty()`?

Comment: You can use the spring `CollectionUtil` or just call `isEmpty()`. Why pull in a full library for just this check. That being said you should import the class not the package, basically your import statement is wrong.

Comment: I have to test smt with CollectionUtils.isEmpty. Are CollectionUtils.isEmpty and isEmpty() the same?

Answer (score 1):

You should fix import for `CollectionUtils`

```
import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> empty_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(empty_list)) {
            System.out.println("List is empty");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you use IntelliJ IDEA - JetBrains. you should do this.

1. In the Maven tool window, right-click a linked project.
2. From the context menu, select Reload project .